# Is it possible to turn off (prevent activation) of a maven profile with gradle? - (unwanted maven profile active)

Tags: java, maven, gradle, zxing

I have an issue with the barcode library zxing.

```
compile('com.google.zxing:core:3.4.1') compile('com.google.zxing:javase:3.4.1')
```

The com.google.zxing **core-3.4.1.pom** is refering to a parent:

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
    <artifactId>zxing-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.1</version>
  </parent>
```

..and the **zxing-parent-3.4.1.pom** contains this snippet

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>build-android</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>env.ANDROID_HOME</name>
        </property>
        <jdk>[,9)</jdk> <!-- Android won't necessarily work with JDK 9 -->
      </activation>
      <modules>
        <module>android-core</module>
        <module>android-integration</module>
        <module>android</module>
      </modules>
      <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>${android.platform}</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <!-- ANDROID_HOME must be absolute, but redundant leading / may help Gradle Spring Boot plugin -->
            <systemPath>/${android.home}/platforms/android-${android.platform}/android.jar</systemPath>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </dependencyManagement>
    </profile>
    <profile>
```

Now the missing systemPath leads to this error:

```
Task :compileJava
Errors occurred while build effective model from C:\Users\eXtensia.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.zxing\core\3.4.1\d1e7c4667f9dcdda30d09f3df7d1b44f65c44336\core-3.4.1.pom:
'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.google.android:android:jar must specify an absolute path but is ${env.ANDROID_HOME}/platforms/android-22/android.jar in com.google.zxing:core:3.4.1
Errors occurred while build effective model from C:\Users\eXtensia.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.zxing\javase\3.4.1\357121cdf3f89f63ddfaad18170612dcad0db947\javase-3.4.1.pom:
'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.google.android:android:jar must specify an absolute path but is ${env.ANDROID_HOME}/platforms/android-22/android.jar in com.google.zxing:javase:3.4.1
```

**Question**

- Gradle: is it possible to turn off this profile with gradle as android is not needed?
- Gradle: Other ways to manipulate the downloaded .pom automatically via gradle to remove this profile?
- Maven: Suggestion how to change the zxing-parent-3.4.1.pom that it will continue to run for android users, non android users and maven/gradle users? (there is already an [issue](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/issues/904) and there are chances to get it changed.)

Comment: that profile is activated on the environment variable ANDROID_HOME or running JDK up to version 8. So it might be enough to just unset that environment variable. Maven also allows to deactivate profiles: "mvn package -P !build-android" - but I'm not sure how the profile causes issues in your gradle build. If the changed dependency and the modules cause issues getting rid of the profile is probably best. Manipulating the parent pom isn't that common. I think some repository proxys allow that but if that turns into the expected result...? You should be able to fork it and remove the activation.

Comment: thanks, ANDROID_HOME is not set but JDK 8 is used. So ok thats the reason for activation than? Mhh just saw it changed in maven since 3.2.2 from OR to AND: http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Activation
But anyway. Seems gradle is not interested in that and just use the profile. Seems only 2 types of activations (activeByDefault, active on the absence of a system property) are considered by gradle (https://blog.gradle.org/maven-pom-profiles)

Comment: well the gradle docs in that regard are correct that the maven profile should not be used in this way. It's usually best to not have an artifact altered with active profiles. The mess you can get into... not sure if the zxing project is willing to fix it as it may break backwards compatibility. If not: fork it is? :/

Comment: thanks. Ticket is closed but they are open for suggestions https://github.com/zxing/zxing/issues/904

Comment: well the readme states "maintenance mode" - so mid or long term one should seek another solution.